# Counting duplicates in a specific column using perl/linux

Tags: linux, perl

I have a file(tab delimited) with 6 columns (here I have shown 2 columns for simplicity)

```
46_#1   A   
47_#1   B   
49_#1   C   
51_#1   D   
51_#1   E
```

I want to count duplicates in first column (only count-no removal) and store count in next column. So output should be-

```
46_#1   1  A    
47_#1   1  B    
49_#1   1  C    
51_#1   2  D    
51_#1   2  E
```

I have used linux command-

```
uniq -c  file
```

but this will take whole line (not 1st column) then I used

```
uniq -c -w5 file
```

But word count in first column can vary.

Can anyone help please?

PS- I have a very big file (around 1gb).

Comment: Are the duplicates always adjacent?

Comment: Oh!sorry I should have mention that. No they can be far away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like just providing complete solutions, but it seemed the easiest way to explain. This program reads through the file twice: first to accumulate the frequency information and then to output the modified data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "No input file specified";

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";

my %count;

while (<$fh>) {
  next unless my ($key) = split;
  $count{$key}++;
}

seek $fh, 0, 0;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  next unless my ($key, $rest) = split ' ', $_, 2;
  print "$key $count{$key} $rest\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is perfectly fine.